# get specific value from database and display it in textboxeson another page

Tags: php

When I click on edit button of first entry from entries.php, I redirect to editentries.php page. And there I want to display the details of first entry only on that page to edit them.But when I click on edit button of first entry I am seeing all the entries in database instead of one specific entry. Help me out what should I do.

This is my entries.php

```
 <?php
            $result01 = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM feedetails");
        while($res=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result01))
        {
        echo '
          <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
            <td>'.$res["name"].'</td>
            <td>'.$res["address"].'</td>
            <td>'.$res["email"].'</td>
            <td>'.$res["phoneno"].'</td>
            <td>'.$res["subjects"].'</td>
            <td>'.$res["price"].'</td>
            <td><form method="post" action="editentries.php"><input type="submit" name="edit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Edit"></form></td>
            <td><form method="post" action="deleteentries.php"><input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" value="Delete" ></form></td>
          </tr>';
      }
          ?>
```

This is editentries.php

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['edit'])){

//$selectid=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM feedetails GROUP BY id");
$selectname=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM feedetails GROUP BY name");
$selectaddress=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM feedetails GROUP BY address");
$selectemail=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM feedetails GROUP BY email");
$selectphoneno=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM feedetails GROUP BY phoneno");
$selectprice=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM feedetails GROUP BY price");


?>

    <form>
      <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Applicant ID:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <select class="form-control">
          <?php  
           for($i=1;$i<=40;$i++)
           {
              echo '<option value="' . $i . '">' . $i . '</option>';  
           }

           ?>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Name:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <?php  while($res=mysqli_fetch_array($selectname)){
            echo '<input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="'.$res['name'].'" >';
          }
           ?>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Address:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
         <?php  while($res=mysqli_fetch_array($selectaddress)){
            echo '<input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="'.$res['address'].'" >';
          }
           ?>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Phone no.:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
         <?php  while($res=mysqli_fetch_array($selectphoneno)){
            echo '<input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="'.$res['phoneno'].'" >';
          }
           ?>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Email ID:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
         <?php  while($res=mysqli_fetch_array($selectemail)){
            echo '<input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="'.$res['email'].'" >';
          }
           ?>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
```

I want to fetch and display only one specific entry from database when I click on edit button. But I am seeing all the entries from database.

Comment: Pass Id in url of edit page: editentries.php'.$res["id"].'

Comment: how do I do that? @DsRaj

Comment: Your query is just `SELECT * FROM feedetails`. You need a `WHERE` conditional in there based on the `$_POST` parameter. Remember to **SANITIZE** it though, using [**prepared statements**](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)  to prevent [**SQL injection**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). And you also only need one query :)

Comment: NO need multiple query for each column. just one query enough and just add where clause to fetch single row .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update html form(entries.php) like this //First you need to pass the id

```
 <tr>
    .
    .
    .
    <td><form method="post" action="editentries.php"><input type="hidden" value="'.$res["id"].'" name="editid"><input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" value="Edit"></form></td>
</tr>
```

in php editentries.php // You need to get the id and update condition with where

```
if(isset($_POST['edit']) && isset($_POST['editid'])){
  $id = $_POST['editid'];
  $selectname=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM feedetails where id = $id GROUP BY name");
.
.//Same for other queries
```

Comment: where clause misplaced

Answer (score 0):

Pass the id in the post param same as you passed the type (edit/delete)). From that id you can make the query which will fetch the specific record. Your query should go something like this:

```
mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM feedetails where id=".$_POST['id']);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In the summary page do like this. 
 <?php
      $result01 = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM feedetails");
  while($res=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result01))
  {
  echo '
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
      <td>'.$res["name"].'</td>
      <td>'.$res["address"].'</td>
      <td>'.$res["email"].'</td>
      <td>'.$res["phoneno"].'</td>
      <td>'.$res["subjects"].'</td>
      <td>'.$res["price"].'</td>
      <td><a href="editentries.php?id='.$res["id"].'"><input type="button" name="edit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Edit"></a></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>';
  }
    ?>

In the edit page, get the id from the url and add where condition in the sql query.
$id = $_REQUEST['id'];
  $selectname=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM feedetails where id = $id GROUP BY name");
```